# start uget as superuser(administrator) from launcher icon

Tags: download-manager, uget

i have recently noticed that, to enable the option "Shutdown When Downloads Complete" in uget I have to start it from terminal with

```
sudo uget-gtk
```

Is there a way to always start uget as a superuser(root) by clicking the icon of uget in launcher.

Comment: I don't believe that's a very good solution... There's [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/uget/+bug/798398) for this. If the download accepts continuing, you could run `sudo shutdown -h 45` to shut down the PC after 45 minutes, for example. You could also use `aria2` (from the command line) plus setting NOPASSWD for `/sbin/shutdown` on `/etc/sudoers` (or using `dbus-send`).

Comment: `dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop` is the dbus-send action @edwin was talking about.

Comment: @MrVaykadji Actually, I was thinking of `dbus-send --type="method_call" --dest=com.canonical.Unity /com/canonical/Unity/Session com.canonical.Unity.Session.Shutdown` if you are using Unity (at least on 14.04 this works). Nonetheless, this won't work unless the OP decides to use an alternative to uGet... At least I don't seem to find a "Run this command on completion" type of option in uGet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We  have fixed this issue for 1.10.5 so in the next release root will no longer be needed but in the meantime...

You first need to install "gksu" which is a tool to run a gtk app as root.

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

1. You can edit the uGet launcher by opening the .desktop file as root. This file is located at /usr/share/applications/uGet.desktop

   gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/uGet.desktop
2. Another option is to install "alacarte" which is a GUI app to edit .desktop files.

   sudo apt-get install alacarte

Both of these options will require you to enter your password every time but that is currently unavoidable.

We may release a beta version of 1.10.5 at some point for testing, at which time the fix for this will be testable.